# Django ORM unable to retrieve database model instances

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm, web-development-server

I am working on a custom user model that subclasses AbstractBaseUser and a custom model manager that subclasses BaseUserManager.This model, Employee, authenticates by email address - USERNAME_FIELD is set to email.

While I can create Employee instances and check my PosgreSQL DB to verify they are being saved, I am unable to retrieve them with the Django ORM and my custom model manager. If I try to retrieve all the employees, or 'get' one employee when running Employee.objects.get(id=1), I get an error that from_db_value() expected 4 arguments but received 5.

I am stumped here. I had this same kind of custom user in another Django 1.11 app and worked fine. I have spent two days trying to resolve this. Any help?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)
from phone_field import PhoneField
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


#  to ensure leading zeroes are captured in badge number
numeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9]*$', 'Only numeric characters are allowed.')

# Create your models here.


class EmployeeManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Employee(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True
    )
    # username = None

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []  # email and password automatically required

    objects = EmployeeManager()

    BUSINESS_UNIT_CHOICES = [
        ('MKT', 'Marketing'),
        ('SLS', 'Sales'),
        ('OPS', 'Operations'),
        ('ADM', 'Adminstrative'),
    ]
    DEPARTMENT_CHOICES = [
        ('EXT', 'Extraction'),
        ('PRD', 'Production'),
        ('QAL', 'Quality'),
        ('PRC', 'Procurement'),
    ]
    LOCATION_CHOICES = [
        ('Menlo Park, CA', 'Menlo Park, California'),
        ('Santa Rosa, CA', 'Santa Rosa, California'),
    ]
    badge_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=4,
        validators=[numeric],
    )
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    business_unit = models.CharField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        choices=BUSINESS_UNIT_CHOICES,
        max_length=3,
        unique=False
    )
    department = models.CharField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        choices=DEPARTMENT_CHOICES,
        max_length=3,
        unique=False
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        max_length=255
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        max_length=255,
    )
    phone = PhoneField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='phone number',
        help_text='Contact phone number'
    )
    job_title = models.CharField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        max_length=255,
        unique=False
    )
    hire_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    location = models.CharField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        choices=LOCATION_CHOICES,
        max_length=255,
        unique=False,
    )

    # password field is builtin
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return F"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def get_phone_number(self):
        return self.phone

    def get_business_unit(self):
        return self.business_unit

    def get_job_title(self):
        return self.job_title

    def get_location(self):
        return self.location

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        #  does user have permissions?
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

settings.py (project level)

```
"""
Django settings for andromeda project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.17.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '1w$d2y4#jmv_763ea3=lj=hjgyu3l^8!fpcy%t%lcj0+yuuoo='

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'andromeda.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'andromeda.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ['DB_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['DB_USER'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['DB_USER_PW'],
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Employee'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('accounts.backends.EmployeeAuth','django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)
```

Stack trace

```
>>> e = Employee.objects.get(id=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/django-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/django-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 374, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/django-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 232, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/django-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1121, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/django-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 62, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/django-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 847, in results_iter
    row = self.apply_converters(row, converters)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/django-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 832, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, self.connection, self.query.context)
TypeError: from_db_value() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
>>>
```

EDIT #1: Figured it out - the django-phone-field module was creating issues.

Comment: Create an answer if you figured this out, please

Answer (score 0):

Removing django phone_field solved the problem. I can now get
Mode instances from the Db using the ORM